# How to redirect to previous page if user deletes last item of current page in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I allow the user to delete items from  paginated content. After deleting the item the user requests i redirect them back. I however have noticed this is buggy because if the page contains only one item and the user deletes it they are redirected to the same page which now has no records.I have 11 items on each page and use the default Laravel pagination. How can i enforce a mechanism that redirects user to the previous page if the current page is blank after deletion of the last or only item?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to do simple check in controller and redirect users manually. The code just shows the idea:

```
$result = Model::paginate(10);
if (count($result) === 0) {
    $lastPage = $result->lastPage(); // Get last page with results.
    $url = route('my-route').'?page='.$lastPage; // Manually build URL.
    return redirect($url);
}

return redirect()->back();
```

Comment: Looks like the problem is rather complicated than l viewed it initially. The delete route and function are different from the items pagination route and function. That means after deleting l redirect back to the item pagination route. This is where l count the number of results after attempting pagination. If the result is zero then l have to redirect again to the items pagination route with the page argument being less by 1. Performing these 2 redirects fails by resulting to ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. Thinking of using same route for delete and pagination of items.

Comment: You can create URI for redirecting when you show paginated results and pass it to delete method when it's just one result on the page. Or send `null` when there are many results. Then use this URI or `back()` if URI `is_null()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the no. of results, if its less than 1 then you can redirect to the `previousPageUrl` as:

```
if ($results->count()) {
    if (! is_null($results->previousPageUrl())) {
        return redirect()->to($results->previousPageUrl());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing a `Redirect::back()` on the delete function. This led to the paginator function where l did the following:

```
//if an item was deleted by the user and it was the only on that page the number of
//items will be zero due the page argument on the url. To solve this we need to
//redirect to the previous page. This is an internal redirect so we just get the
//current arguments and reduce the page number by 1. If the page argument is not
//available it means that we are on the first page. This way we either land on the
//first page or a previous page that has items
$input = Input::all();
if( (count($pages) == 0) && ( array_key_exists('page', $input) ) ){
    if($input['page'] < 2){
        //we are headed for the first page
        unset($input['page']);
        return redirect()->action('MyController@showItems', $input);
    }
    else{
        //we are headed for the previous page -- recursive
        $input['page'] -= 1;
        return redirect()->action('MyController@showItems', $input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement such a logic in the controller method, `destroy()`, we need to know the current page number, and the items count (before we delete this item).

Pass these two pieces of information through the *`DELETE`* link, and retrieve them using the `Request` `input` method.

In your view:

```
<form action="{{'/items/'.$item->id.'?current_page='.$items->currentPage().'&items_count='.$items->count()}}" method="POST">
 @method('DELETE')
 @csrf
 <button>Delete</button>
</form>
```

In your controller:

```
public function destroy(Item $item, Request $request)
{
    $item->delete();
    $itemsCount = $request->input('items_count');
    $currentPage = $request->input('current_page');
    $url = $itemsCount > 1 ? '/items/?page='.$currentPage : '/items/?page='.($currentPage - 1);
    return redirect($url);
}
```

If it's the last page (1), then the page number becomes 0, which will still return the correct response (empty items list).

For the routes, implement a route with the two parameters, with the controller's destroy method as the callback.
If you have a resource controller, then this route has to be before the latter's route.

web.php

```
Route::DELETE('/items/{item_id}?current_page={number}&items_count={count}', 'ItemController@destroy');

Route::resource('/items', 'ItemController');
```